# What is runtime a single loop but it's run n-amount of times?

Tags: runtime, big-o

For example, bubble sort -- why is that O(n^2) if it's running through a single loop n-amount of times?  Wouldn't it be O(n) since you are technically iterating through a single loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is that O(n^2) if it's running through a single loop n-amount of times?

Easy, your loop is **O(n)**. Right? So if you loop **n times** a loop is:
**n x O(n) = O(N²)**

Comment: ah got it, thanks for explaining that.  I thought O(n^2) almost always referred to nested loops only.  Thank you